# set chart type property in devexpress chart control c#

Tags: c#, charts, highcharts, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I created a chart in my dashboard of my program as you can see :

[image]

I initialize the data with this code in my load_form

```
   chartControlMIVBaseDateTime.DataSource = _materialIssueVoucherRepository.ViewImivBasedOnDates().ToList();


            // Generate a data table and bind the chart to it.

            // Specify data members to bind the chart's series template.
            chartControlMIVBaseDateTime.SeriesDataMember = "Count";
            chartControlMIVBaseDateTime.SeriesTemplate.ArgumentDataMember = "DateTime";
            chartControlMIVBaseDateTime.SeriesTemplate.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Count" });
```

The Count in numerical ,but the problem is i set the chart to show this type of presentation

[image]

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code

```
 Series series = new Series("Series1", ViewType.Spline);

            chartControlMIVBaseDateTime.Series.Add(series);

            // Generate a data table and bind the series to it.
            series.DataSource = _materialIssueVoucherRepository.ViewImivBasedOnDates().ToList();

            // Specify data members to bind the series.
            series.ArgumentScaleType = ScaleType.DateTime;
            series.ArgumentDataMember = "DateTime";
            series.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.Numerical;
            series.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "Count" });
```